# Is catching 4xx errors enough?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, http, http-status-codes

Catching 4xx and 5xx errors seems unnecessary and hard. Is it enough to only catch 4xx errors? When would even a 5xx error appear if I test my code regularly?

Comment: _Regularly_ testing your code doesn't tell you anything about the quality and scope of the test or the quality of the software your stuff is running on. And nobody is able to write code without ever making an error or without missing an obscure code path that then will cause an error... Or is your backend 100% free of bugs/problems? Has it a guaranteed uptime of 100%? Is the server hosted in a data center that's protected from any environmental damage? ...

Answer (score 1):

Is it enough to only catch 4xx errors? - Nope

4xx error are **client side** related errors - a bad(corrupted request was sent), or a unauthorized request was sent(401), ooor the requested page is missing or not found (404). These three are the most common one.

When would even a 5xx error appear if I test my code regularly?
5xx errors are **server side** errors and that means something on the server has gone wrong.

In any case you should implement reasonable error handling on the front end in order to avoid user frustration and handle different error cases accordingly.